# how to put dependency in maven not in WEB-INF/lib

Tags: maven-2, maven

Is there a way to put dependency of a war not in WEB-INF/lib but in out custom folder?

I'm using Maven 2

Hi, what i need is that from list of dependencies of a war only one artifact should be placed not in WEB-INF/lib but in WEB-INF/bundles/ and others dependencies should be places in WEB-INF/lib

thx

THX to everybody, i can't update to Maven 2.1 so i did it through maven-antrun plugin )

Comment: Why do you need to place this jar file in `/WEB-INF/bundles`?

Comment: Our apache felix is configured to search for bundles only in this folder (that is not WEB-INF/lib)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you need to do is make the dependency `provided` and copy it using [`mvn copy-dependencies`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html). Here is an example that does that with apache commons / lang:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copydep</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <inherited>false</inherited>
                    <configuration>
                        <includeArtifactIds>commons-lang</includeArtifactIds>
                        <outputDirectory>$project.build.directory/${project.build.finalName}/web-inf/bundles</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

(`$project.build.directory/${project.build.finalName}` is the work folder that is used to assemble the war)

Comment: I'm using Maven 2.0.9 and it didn't place artifact in any directory i specify (( I didn't understand why :)

Comment: Do you know if prepare-package phase exists in Maven 2.0.9 ?

Comment: prepare-package definitely did exist back then. maybe you could run the command with the -XD flag, pipe it to a file and post the output on pastebin, then we could see what's happening: ` mvn clean install -X > myfile.txt`

Comment: Actually, `prepare-package` is only available in Maven 2.1 and above (http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html). Still, this is the best suggestion so far (and I'm not sure there is a better one). +1

Comment: well okay, it should be possible to put it in the package or process-classes phase, then. (package is probably not a good idea as old maven versions are not reliable concering execution order in one phase)

Comment: Yeah, process-classes should work. Or just upgrade to Maven 2.2.1^w 3.0 :)

Comment: I have the same problem, but the jar isn't a dependency. I'm building an webapp based on BIRT, and BIRT isn't mavenized. It requires several jars on WEB-INF/platform/plugins. However, when the war file is built it moves the jars from WEB-INF/platform/plugins to WEB-INF/lib. As these jars aren't dependencies I can't use <scope>provided</scope>...

Comment: @muriloq please ask a separate question if you want answers

Answer (score 0):

[Maven war plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/) supports extensive customization.  Not clear from your question, what exactly you want, but [this page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html) should hopefully help.

Comment: Hi, what i need is that from list of dependencies of a war only one artifact should be placed not in WEB-INF/lib but in WEB-INF/bundles/ and others dependencies should be places in WEB-INF/lib

Comment: Maven war plugin won't help here, it doesn't support such an option

Answer (score 0):

Where do you want to put these libraries? You have to be carefull, as the [war structure](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/WCC3.html) defines the `WEB-INF/lib` as the directory for third-parties libraries. All `*.jar` files located in this directory will be loaded in the Classpath by the container (such as Tomcat).

Changing this directory can be harmful for your application!

That's why I am not aware of a configuration parameter for the [Maven WAR Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin) that allow you to change this `WEB-INF/lib` directory.

If you really know what you are doing, you can try to create your own WAR using an [assembly](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/).